# Verilog - When would it be useful to manually set an output to high impedance?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I was thinking one use would be to indicate that the output of this pin should not be considered (yet). Is this why 'high impedance' is normally used on output pins?

Comment: Tri-state buffers. You drive 0 or 1 or let someone else drive the value.

Answer (score 0):

I2C SDA and SCL pins could be one of the use.